How do I make text italic in MacVim, since it works in iTerm2?
When I write e.g. *foo* in Markdown files using Vim from iTerm2, then foo "foo" (italic) as expected. If I do the same in the MacVim GUI it won't be displayed as italic, but as normal text, i.e., as "foo".
The command :set guifont? returns guifont=Fira Code:h12. Also, iTerm2 > Settings > Profiles > Text-Font has "Fira Code" selected. From iTerm2: which vim returns
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/vim

However:

If I write **foo** then foo it is displayed as "foo" (bold) in both iTerm2 Vim and MacVim GUI.
If I :set guifont= then *foo* is displayed as "foo" (italic) in both iTerm2 Vim and MacVim GUI.

How to make *foo* to be displayed in italic on MacVim while using Fira Code fonts?

I can't reproduce (using VictorMono-Regular:h12): both MacVim (9.1) and Vim (9.1.516) show italics for me. Some things to check: (a) syntax and highlight groups: I get markdownItalic, which is setup with both cterm=italic and gui=italic; (b) your path to Vim looks strange: I have /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim for MacVim (but /usr/local/bin/vim for Vim because I mostly use a non-GUI-compiled Vim); (c) do you have italic FiraCode fonts, too?

Thanks! (a) I have the same, (b) MacVim ships with both gui and terminal version, so I don't see anything strange in my paths, (c) surprisingly there is no italic style in Fira Code, yet the terminal Vim version render markdown italic text in italic.

Add some more elements: tested on Windows and WSL2 (Ubuntu) and everything works fine. Maybe a MacVim issue?

Could be, except that again with my font I don't see it ;) The path that looks odd is /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/vim/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/vim: perhaps that's just pasting the same path twice, though

Auch! It is pasted twice. I corrected it.
